# xcode importLocalization hangs on command line

Tags: xcode, localization

I am trying to automate the import of localization files in xcode, but when I run the command it just hangs there - any way to debug?

The xliff files import just fine when I do it by hand manually by going to editor -> import localization

This is what I run
xcodebuild -importLocalizations -verbose -localizationPath myPathHere -project myProject.xcodeproj